# Get glossy shading but no reflections (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

If you use a glossy/shiny material, it will have certain shading. It will also reflect the world environment color, and nearby objects in the scene. Is there a way to make it so that you still have glossy shading, but that you don't get reflections?

EDIT: Picture for clarification. Here we have a sphere with Diffuse and Glossy mixed based on fresnel, with no roughness. So it is a very shiny, reflective sphere. We can see that it is shaded by the glossy node, being lighter towards the edges (as fresnel does.) It is also reflecting the blue cube. I would like it to keep its shading, but not pick up reflections of nearby objects. If I increase its roughness, it still reflects the cube, it just looks more blurred.

The purpose of this is to be able to do non-photorealism where I can control what my shading looks like without it also increasing reflections. For example, the settings that you would use it have large, hard-edged toony specular highlights would also result in those areas being very reflective, which is not how they behave in toon styles.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by, "Is there a way to make it so that you still have glossy shading, but that you don't get reflections?". Are you trying to make it not reflect the environment and certain objects?.

Comment: @Wyvernul Correct. I want it to respond to the lighting, and form highlights on the object, but not pick up reflections of the environment or objects.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend? If you simply increase the roughness on a glossy BSDF you can get non-sharp highlights from light sources but I am not sure that is what you are trying to achieve. What is the end result material you are trying to create?

Comment: @Wyvernul Updated with a picture.

Comment: "We can see that it is shaded by the glossy node, being lighter towards the edges (as fresnel does.)"  I am a little confused with how you are using the word shading here. Do you want the object to be lighter towards the edges but with no specular reflections?

Answer (score 7):

Here I have a sphere reflecting the two objects and environment.
[image]

If you don't want an object to be reflected just select it, go to the *Object* header and uncheck the ***Glossy*** box in the *Ray Visibility* panel.
[image]
[image]

If you want to see the objects reflected, but without the reflection of the environment, go to the *World* material settings in a *Node Editor* and set up the nodes as pictured below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I need, but I actually need the reverse. This lets me make an object not show up in reflections, but then it doesn't show up in ANY reflections. I want to be able to have a material that doesn't reflect objects, but I may still need other materials to reflect them.

Answer (score 1):

If i (hypothetically) am following correctly, you want an object not to be reflected on a certain glossy object, while still retaining its reflection on other glossy objects. If this is correct and also needed for an animation and or single frame render(s) and not other programs such as unity or unreal, etc. Than could you not render in layers and use the video sequencer and compositor to create the scene from two separate layers?. Example being render one scene with no reflections and high roughness on gloss shader, than render full environment shader with scene giving reflections on objects. Than use editing programs to layer the scene to refeclt where u want reflections or not.

P. S. I am fairly new with modelling and game engines, so this question would be a lot cooler if it gets an answer. ( sad Matt mack in Dazed and confused reference.)