# Reflection problem on mirror object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, node-editor

I'm working on a project that uses backplates and then I am doing character animation seperately and compositing the animation over the backplate.
When doing the character animation I try and match the lighting and since scenes are indoors I create "lightblockers" that represent the walls, ceiling and floors.  All of these "lightblockers" have *Ray Visablity* turned off for the camera.

I have a scene that makes it necessary for me to use a large wall mirror so I can reflect the character in the mirror.  My problem is that these"lightblockers walls" are showing up in the mirror. I need only the character/treadmill to reflect in the mirror.

On the mirror object material (full glossy) I tried using a lightpath node but had no luck. (tried nearly every socket: glossy > mixnode Lightpath > to factor of mixnode)

[image: screencap_mirror_problem]

If you look at the rendered image you can see the lightblockers are not shown in the scene but do reflect in the mirror.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  This is a screengrab after making suggested changes:

[image: screengrab2_afterchanges]

How can I make that black area on the mirror transparant?
Instead of showing black, while still keeping the character/treadmill in the reflection.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36425/get-glossy-shading-but-no-reflections-cycles

Comment: What nodes are you using for the lightblockers?

Comment: You may be able to do some tricks with the *is glossy ray* light path node to make the walls invisible to the mirror, depending on what the nodes are for the walls.

Comment: @ptex  Lightblockers had just a diffused shader and then I had ray visability for the camera turned off for all lightblockers Your trick of disabling ray visability glossy for the lightblocker worked great and now the lightblockers cant be seen in the mirror ... thanks .... but I'm still not there... see next post...I cant add a new image here for some reason.

Comment: @cegaton  Thanks for the link ..it helped  I made the change to my world settings (adding lightpath node.... is camera.  It elimanted the world light from the mirror and left me the character/only ... HOWEVER... now I have total black on the mirror xcept the character....  how can I make the black transparant...so I am only left with the character/treadmill.  Im going to post a screen grab onto my original post if possible

Comment: can you post your .blend file. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @cegatonI I can, but it wont be for a couple hours.... were just leaving

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=543" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/543/)       heres the blend... I had to use a proxy treadmill... hdri image is packed

Comment: I haven't seen any replies after i posted the blend file so maybe there just isn't a way to remove the black that is showing in the mirror.  I was able to bring it into my compositor and basically key out the black in the mirror.  It involved a little masking, but seems to work OK.