# World background that is not reflected by Glossy objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, node-editor

I have a glossy object with a sky texture as world background. What I need is for the glossy object to not reflect the background and for the background to still be visible.

I tried this setup: [Get glossy shading but no reflections (Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36425/get-glossy-shading-but-no-reflections-cycles)
but this makes the bakground go black.

My setup screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the world background not affect Glossy surfaces you can simply disable the 'Glossy' Ray Visibility for the background :

[image: background ray visibility]

Here the background has been made invisible for Glossy rays (so there is no reflection in the Glossy cube) but the background is still visible to the camera and still used to illuminate Suzanne (who is also shown reflected in the surface of the cube).